# Java, юнит тест - как тестируются сложные методы

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Есть метод который вызывает остальные методы

[image: method]

результат работы метода

```
123456 | 15 
120    +-----
       |8230
______
  34
  30
______
   45
   30
______
   156
   150
______
     6
```

Как мне его тестировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете проверить потому что слишком сложный код написали! Другими словами, если Вы не можете сходу и быстро написать тест, значит что-то с production-кодом не совсем просто! Сейчас вы тест не можете, в будущем понять и поправить или добавить что-то.

Вывод: Если тест написать сложно, упрощайте код!

Давайте подсчитаем сколько выходов или изменений внешнего мира у Вашего метода?

1. `result.append` - одна штука
2. `printTop`, `printCornel`, `printLine` - еще три штуки
3. `result.append`, `printShift` два раза , `printLine` и это не  паросто три вызова, а три умножить на кол-во итераций!
4. Исключения могут быть брошены?

Вы слишком сложную логику написали!

Answer (score 0):

Ты тестишь общий метод, можешь и внутренние тоже. А потом тестишь разные результаты и ошибки, если ты сделал на них проверку, например, деление на 0.